# Variables in ES6 Namespace

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, namespaces

Assume I have the following namespaces

```
window.myNameSpace.1.someName

window.myNameSpace.2.someName
```

Also, assume that I have a runtime variable `x`, where `x` could be either `1` or `2`

```
let x = 1; // x is 1 in this case, but could be 2
```

Now, based on the value of `x`, I could do this

```
switch (x) {
    
    case 1:
        let someName = window.myNameSpace.1.someName;
        break;

    case 2
        let someName = window.myNameSpace.2.someName;
        break;
}
```

This works and is great.

However, can I do something like this to make code more concise? (please note this is a pseudo code and not correct, this is the idea)

```
let someName = window.myNameSpace.<x>.someName; // replace <x> with the variable
```

And thus making the code much shorter and more efficient, especially if I have a lot of values for `x` and a number of namespaces.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about accessing an object property dynamically? `let myVariable = 'myKey'; let someName = window.myNameSpace[myVariable].someName;`

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky - Thanks. So the `myVariable` has to be a string? And does it work in namespaces? I will try this. Thanks again.

Comment: Did you try it with both a number or a string, what happens?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky - About to try it now.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky - Number does not work, however your suggestion in the comment above works as a string. Maybe you like to add your comment as an answer? For future reference. Thanks a lot.

Comment: For whoever closed the question, this is not the same as the suggested duplicate. Please re-oopen

Comment: It does work with numbers: https://jsfiddle.net/kygtac83/

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky - You are right. I did something else. Apologies. Thanks again.